# OpenCV Image To Matrix In txt files

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am doing this to get each pixel value of Image and printing it on Console

```
include "stdafx.h"
include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
include <stdlib.h>
include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg");
    CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC3 );
    cvConvert( img, mat );
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
         for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
           {
              CvScalar scal = cvGet2D( mat,j,i);
              printf( "(%.f,%.f,%.f)  ",scal.val[0], scal.val[1], scal.val[2] );
           }
         printf("\n");
       }
    waitKey(1);
    return 0;
 }
```

Is there better way to get each pixel value along with there header and channel values in txt.files

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'better'? What exactly do you not like about the way you are currently using?

Comment: Just an FYI: Since you are using C++, you could simplify the code a bit and do `cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`.

Comment: Currently I am using for loop to get each pixel value. Is there a single function to do this and it's gets printed in dos prompt but i want to save this matrix value in txt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend against using the C API if you can help it. The C++ API is much easier to use. As for storage of a matrix in a file, have a look at the [FileStorage](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=filestorage#FileStorage) class available in OpenCV.

It's as easy as:

### Write

```
FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1000, 0, 320, 0, 1000, 240, 0, 0, 1);
fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix;
...
fs.release();
```

### Read

```
FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);

Mat cameraMatrixFromFile;
fs["cameraMatrix"] >> cameraMatrixFromFile;
...
fs.release();
```

Hope that helps!